# Finding Mouse Hovering

Tags: java

I am currently working on creating a game with Java and I wanted to create a hover effect. Whenever the mouse is hovering over a rectangle that i created in the Gui i wanted a boolean to be set to true or false. I am not sure what i did wrong. Here is my code:

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import com.tutorial.main.Game.STATE;

public class Shop extends MouseAdapter{

    private Game game;
    private Handler handler;
    private Random r = new Random();
    private HUD hud;
    private boolean enough_maxhealth = true;
    private boolean enough_speed = true;
    private boolean enough_frozen = true;
    private boolean enough_blast = true;
    private boolean health_info = false;
    private boolean speed_info = false;
    private boolean freeze_info = false;
    private boolean blast_info = false;

    //static to show other classes what is upgraded, can be implemented so it won't have to in future
    public static int[] upgrades = {0,0,3,0};
    private static int[] prices =  {1,2,1,5};

    //way program is built, coin has to be static
    public static int COIN = 0;

    private int shop_timer = 0;

    //check if this is needed
    private int timer_frozen_upgrade = 100;

    public Shop(Game game, Handler handler, HUD hud){
        this.game = game;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.hud = hud;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        int mx = e.getX();
        int my = e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        int mx = e.getX();
        int my = e.getY();




        //Shop buttons
        if(game.gameState == STATE.Shop){
            //back button
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 350, 200, 64)){
                game.gameState = STATE.Game;
                return;

            }
            //health upgrade
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, 80, 110, 150, 50)){
                // Cost 1 coins for + 10 health
                if (COIN >= prices[0]){
                    //checks if maxed, 3 is the max
                    if (upgrades[0] < 3){
                        //updates upgrades
                        upgrades[0] += 1;
                        //adds 10 health to players max health
                        HUD.MAX_HEALTH += 10;
                        COIN -= prices[0];
                    }
                }else{
                    //set a message to be shown for 40 ticks
                    shop_timer = 40;
                    //signifies that you don't have enough
                    enough_maxhealth = false;
                }
            }

            //back button
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, 230, 380, 200, 64)){

                game.gameState = STATE.Game;

            }
            //speed upgrade
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, 80, 200, 150, 50)){
                if(COIN >= prices[1]){
                    if(upgrades[1] < 3){
                        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
                            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
                            if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
                                //increases player default Vx and Vy by 108%
                                tempObject.setVx_Default(tempObject.getVx_Default() * 1.08f);
                                tempObject.setVy_Default(tempObject.getVy_Default() * 1.08f);
                                //costs 2 coins
                                COIN -= prices[1];
                                upgrades[1] += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    //set a message to be shown for 40 ticks
                    shop_timer = 40;
                    enough_speed = false;
                }
            }
            //Freeze enemies
            /*
            if(mouseOver(mx, mx, Game.WIDTH - 230, 110, 150, 50)){
                System.out.println("Pressed buy");
                if(COIN >= 2){
                    if(upgrades[2] < 3){
                        upgrades[2] += 1;
                        System.out.println("Bought frozen");

                    }
                }
            }*/
            //freeze
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, Game.WIDTH - 230, 110, 150, 50)){
                if(COIN >= prices[2]){
                    //if(upgrades[2] < 3){
                        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
                            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
                            if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
                                //increases player default Vx and Vy by 108%
                                COIN -= prices[2];
                                upgrades[2] += 1;
                            }
                        //}
                    }
                }else{
                    //set a message to be shown for 40 ticks
                    shop_timer = 40;
                    enough_frozen = false;
                }
            }
            //blast
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, Game.WIDTH - 230, 200, 150, 50)){
                if(COIN >= prices[3]){
                    if(upgrades[3] < 2){
                        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
                            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
                            if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
                                //increases player default Vx and Vy by 108%
                                COIN -= prices[3];
                                upgrades[3] += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    //set a message to be shown for 40 ticks
                    shop_timer = 40;
                    enough_blast = false;
                }
            }

        }



    }


    //returns true or false depends of mouse is over certain cordinates
    private boolean mouseOver(int mx, int my, int x, int y, int width, int height){
        if(mx > x && mx < x + width){
            if (my > y && my < y + height){
                return true;
            }else return false;
        }else return false;     
    }


    //checks if the mouse has entered one of the rectangles
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        int mx = e.getX();
        int my = e.getY();

        //Shop buttons
        if(game.gameState == STATE.Shop){
            //health box
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, 80, 110, 150, 50)){
                health_info = true;
            }else{
                health_info = false;
            }

            //speed box
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, 80, 200, 150, 50)){
                speed_info = true;
            }else{
                speed_info = false;
            }

            //freeze box
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, 410, 110, 150, 50)){
                freeze_info = true;
            }
            else freeze_info = false;

            //blast box
            if(mouseOver(mx, my, 410, 200, 150, 50)){
                blast_info = true;
            }else{
                blast_info = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //checks if the mouse has exited one of the rectangles
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            int mx = e.getX();
            int my = e.getY();

            //Shop buttons
            if(game.gameState == STATE.Shop){
                //health box
                if(mouseOver(mx, my, 80, 110, 150, 50)){
                    health_info = false;
                }else{
                    health_info = true;
                }

                //speed box
                if(mouseOver(mx, my, 80, 200, 150, 50)){
                    speed_info = false;
                }else{
                    speed_info = true;
                }

                //freeze box
                if(mx > 110 && mx < 410){
                    if(my > 50 && my < 150){
                        freeze_info = false;
                        System.out.println("exit in");
                    }
                    else{
                        freeze_info = true;
                        System.out.println("exit left");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    freeze_info = true;
                    System.out.println("exit left");
                }

                //blast box
                if(mouseOver(mx, my, 410, 200, 150, 50)){
                    blast_info = false;
                }else{
                    blast_info = true;
                }
            }
        }

    public void tick(){
        //reduces shop timer that shows message
        if(shop_timer >= 0){
            shop_timer--;
        }       
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){

        //try to simplify/optimize

        //Shop System
        if(game.gameState == STATE.Shop){

            //creates fonts for future reference

            Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
            Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 20);
            Font fnt3 = new Font("arial", 1, 17);
            Font fnt4 = new Font("arial", 1, 11);
            Font fnt5 = new Font("arial", 1, 9);
            Font fnt6 = new Font("arial", 1, 40);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);


            g.setColor(Color.gray);

            g.setFont(fnt);

            g.drawString("Shop", 250, 50);

            //Displays Health
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(15, 15, 200, 32);
            g.setColor(new Color(75, (int) HUD.greenValue, 0));
            g.fillRect(15,15, (int) HUD.HEALTH * 2, 32);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawRect(15, 15, 200, 32);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.white);

            //Health upgrade
            g.drawRect(80, 110, 150, 50);
            g.drawString("Max Health", 90, 140);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            if(upgrades[0] >= 1){
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            }
            g.fillRect(82, 170, 44, 14);
            if(upgrades[0] >= 2){
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            }else{
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
            }
            g.fillRect(134, 170, 44, 14);
            if(upgrades[0] >= 3){
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            }else{
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
            }
            g.fillRect(186, 170, 44, 14);



            //Speed upgrade
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawRect(80, 200, 150, 50);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            if(upgrades[1] >= 1){
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            }
            g.fillRect(82, 260, 44, 16);
            if(upgrades[1] >= 2){
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            }else{
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
            }
            g.fillRect(134, 260, 44, 16);
            if(upgrades[1] >= 3){
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            }else{
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
            }
            g.fillRect(186, 260, 44, 16);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(fnt3);
            g.drawString("Speed Upgrade", 82, 230);


            //freeze enemy effect
            g.drawRect(Game.WIDTH - 230, 110, 150, 50);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(fnt3);
            g.drawString("Freze Enemy", Game.WIDTH - 215, 140);
            g.setFont(fnt4);
            if(freeze_info){
                g.drawString("Press 'f' to slow enemies", Game.WIDTH - 230, 173 );
                g.drawString("(Can only be used once)", Game.WIDTH - 228, 185);
            }
                g.setFont(fnt6);
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawString("" + upgrades[2], 590, 150);


            //blast for some odd ticks

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawRect(Game.WIDTH - 230, 200, 150, 50);
            //g.setColor(Color.gray);
            //g.fillRect(80, 210, 33, 10);
            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.drawString("Blast", Game.WIDTH - 190, 230);
            g.setFont(fnt4);
            g.drawString("Press 'ctrl' for Imunity", Game.WIDTH - 230, 263 );
            g.drawString("(Can only be used once)", Game.WIDTH - 228, 278);
            g.setFont(fnt6);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawString("" + upgrades[3], 590, 240);

            g.setFont(fnt);

            //back button
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawRect(230, 380, 200, 64);
            g.drawString("Back", 260, 430);

            if(!enough_maxhealth || !enough_speed || !enough_frozen || !enough_blast){
                if(shop_timer > 0){
                    System.out.println(shop_timer);
                    g.setFont(fnt2);
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                    if(!enough_maxhealth){
                        g.drawString("You need " + (prices[0] - COIN) + " coins more", 190, 90);
                    }else if(!enough_speed){
                        g.drawString("You need " + (prices[1] - COIN) + " coins more", 190, 90);
                    }else if(!enough_frozen){
                        g.drawString("You need " + (prices[2] - COIN) + " coins more", 190, 90);
                    }else if(!enough_blast){
                        g.drawString("You need " + (prices[3] - COIN) + " coins more", 190, 90);
                    }
                }else{
                    enough_maxhealth = true;
                    enough_speed = true;
                    enough_frozen = true;
                    enough_blast = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I tried to change some things with the freeze to see if it would effect the way it worked, but it still isn't properly working. The boolean for freeze is set to true in MouseExit whenever i leave the GUI, but i cannot make it correspond to the rectangle.

Comment: What class are these methods in?  If it's a frame or panel class or something like that, you won't get mouseEntered and mouseExited events unless the mouse leaves the entire frame or panel.  I don't think that's what you want.  You'll need to implement mouseEntered and mouseExited on the individual buttons.

Comment: i didn't make any buttons though. I just created rectangles and if the mouse was clicked within its bounds it would do something. The class i have it in is a shop class which extends MouseAdapter

Comment: How is the hover effect achieved when the boolean is updated?  Does some component need to be `repainted()`?

Comment: OK, how did you create the rectangles?  Did you use some kind of control that can receives mouseEntered and mouseExited events?

Comment: my plan was that whenever the mouse was over a certain rectaingle the bool would be set to true and a drawString would be made that has some info. The rectangles were just created with the drawRectangle within a certain bound. Whener i wanted to use mousePressed or such i just put in those bounds

Comment: Yeah, rectangles drawn that way don't generate mouseEntered and mouseExited events.  You could try mouseMoved instead.

Comment: how would i make mouseMoved go within a certain parameter?

Comment: Exactly how you've tried to do it for mouseEntered.

Comment: I switched mouseEntered to mouseMoved, but there was no change

Comment: So use your debugger to find out whether it's getting fired.

Comment: Did you add your MouseAdapter as a listener to your GUI anywhere?

Comment: yes i added the listenener and i found out that only the else statement in the mouseExit get called

Answer (score 0):

The class Rectangle2D has methods for testing collisions with other rectangles and/or a single point.

> Tests if the specified coordinates are inside the boundary of the
>   Shape

```
contains(double x, double y)
```

and

> Tests if the interior of the Shape entirely contains the specified
>   rectangular area.

```
contains(double x, double y, double w, double h)
```

I'd suggest refactoring your code to use these instead, and write some unit tests if you don't have any to prove it works.

Extend from this class to inherit the functionality for your objects

******************** EDITS ********************

```
class SomeObjectToRepresent extends Rectangle2D {
   @override
   public boolean contains(x, y){
      boolean b = super.contains(x, y);
      // change the state based on b
   }
}
```

Something like the above but not exactly, just trying to point you in the right direction.

As for mouse events I would recommend using the MouseMotionListener 
 instead and use mouseMoved event and check your components, set their state based on whether the mouse is within bounds of your component by updating a list of components in your application. A component manager can do this or your JFrame can whenever a mouse event is obtained.
It's more brutish to do this but it's very easy to implement and I doubt you'll have many components.
Since every time the mouse moves that list will be updated or at least touched on. 
I'm trying to find out where this was but you may need to add your mouse listener twice, one for motion and another for just the original. I know that sounds strange but I vaguely remember this being a problem for me too when events were not firing.

[Rectangle2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html)

Comment: I added the full code above for the class. I am not sure where I am supposed to add the contains.